# replace loop for iteration with two rows with multiple if condition python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I have following code, I am using loop for further operation.

```
for i in range(0,(len(dff1)-1)):
    lat1=dff1.latitude.values[i]
    lon1=dff1.longitude.values[i]
    lat2=dff1.latitude.values[i+1]
    lon2=dff1.longitude.values[i+1]
    if((lat1!=0)&(lon1!=0)&(lat2!=0)&(lon2!=0)):
        a=(lat1,lon1)
        b=(lat2,lon2)
        s=i
        dist.append(great_circle(a,b).meters)
    elif((lat1==0)&(lon1==0)&(lat2==0)&(lon2==0)):
        dist.append(0)
    elif((lat1!=0)&(lon1!=0)&(lat2==0)&(lon2==0)):
        dist.append(0)
    elif((lat1==0)&(lon1==0)&(lat2!=0)&(lon2!=0)):
        pp=list(range(s,i+1))
        lst=[]
        for y in pp:
            lst.append(dff1.latitude.values[y])
        ls = [z for z, e in enumerate(lst) if e != 0]
        lst1=[]
        for q in pp:
            lst1.append(dff1.longitude.values[q])
        ls = [z for z, e in enumerate(lst) if e != 0]
        ls1 = [z for z, e in enumerate(lst1) if e != 0]
        lat1=lst[ls[-1]]
        lon1=lst1[ls[-1]]
        a=(lat1,lon1)
        b=(lat2,lon2)
        dist.append(great_circle(a,b).meters)
```

I am storing the lat, long from each row and their previous row I am getting 4 variable i.e. lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, Now I am using the conditions like if all variable values are zero, append 0, like that I have 4 conditions and using another function called great_circleto calculate some value with those four variables with the last condition written in the code and appending it to the list.

I want to replace loop as its taking too long to execute, when the size of the data frame is large.

How to do it without loop so, it can execute faster

Comment: Please also explain what your loop is trying to achieve/

Comment: You need to explain what calculation and what  conditions. Volunteers here won't put so much effort into completely understanding your code. Make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Also add your dummy dataframe.

Comment: In the case of lat/lon it's not too much of a push to imagine the df contents. You're trying to build a distance matrix?

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, I am putting the distances in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, you have a dataframe with longitude and latitude, and you want to calculate the distance to the long and lat located in the following row, and store that value as distance.

Dummy dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Long':[-2986.242495,-3383.296608,0,0],'Lat':[-880.627428,-2559.748913,0,0]})

df
Lat             Long
-880.627428     -2986.242495
-2559.748913    -3383.296608
0.000000        0.000000
0.000000        0.000000
```

instead of doing a loop where you assign i+1 into lat2 and long2 you can simply shift the dataframe and store the values into new columns as per below

```
df[['Long_2','Lat_2']] = df[['Long','Lat']].shift(-1)

df
Lat             Long            Long_2          Lat_2
-880.627428     -2986.242495    -3383.296608    -2559.748913
-2559.748913    -3383.296608    0.000000        0.000000
0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000
0.000000        0.000000        NaN             NaN
```

we can then create a Distance columns which we give None as default value, and 0 where all columns are 0

```
df['Distance'] = None
df.loc[(df.Lat==0) & (df.Long==0) & (df.Lat_2==0) & (df.Long_2==0),'Distance'] = 0
```

where all the columns aren't 0 we use our distance formula to calculate the distance

```
df.loc[df.Distance!=0,'Distance'] = sphere_dist(df.loc[df.Distance!=0,'Lat'],df.loc[df.Distance!=0,'Long'],df.loc[df.Distance!=0,'Lat_2'],df.loc[df.Distance!=0,'Long_2'])
```

and now we have a dataframe with the result we're (hopefully) after in the Distance columns

```
df
Lat              Long           Long_2          Lat_2            Distance
-880.627428     -2986.242495    -3383.296608    -2559.748913    12400
-2559.748913    -3383.296608    0.000000        0.000000        14239.1
0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0
0.000000        0.000000        NaN             NaN             NaN
```

The formula I used here is

```
def sphere_dist(pickup_lat, pickup_lon, dropoff_lat, dropoff_lon):
    """
    Return distance along great radius between first and second coordinates.
    """
    #Define earth radius (km)
    R_earth = 6371
    #Convert degrees to radians
    pickup_lat, pickup_lon, dropoff_lat, dropoff_lon = map(np.radians,
                                                             [pickup_lat, pickup_lon, 
                                                              dropoff_lat, dropoff_lon])
    #Compute distances along lat, lon dimensions
    dlat = dropoff_lat - pickup_lat
    dlon = dropoff_lon - pickup_lon

    #Compute haversine distance
    a = np.sin(dlat/2.0)**2 + np.cos(pickup_lat) * np.cos(dropoff_lat) * np.sin(dlon/2.0)**2

    return 2 * R_earth * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
```

Comment: This is okay but except one condition, lets see if lat!=0 and long!=0 but lat2=0 and long2 =0, in that case I want o calculate it with last nonzero lat2 and long2 (last nonzero lat2 and long2 just above it)

Comment: SUre, just replace 0 with None and then ffill where it's 0 in lat2 and long2 but not in lat1 and long1.

`df.loc[((df['Long']!=0) & (df['Lat']!=0)) & ((df['Long_2']==0) & (df['Lat_2']==0)),['Long_2','Lat_2']] = None`

`df[['Long_2','Lat_2']] = df[['Long_2','Lat_2']].fillna(method='ffill')`

Comment: I dont want to fill just previous values, I want to calculate the distance again with the previous nonzero lat - long with the the current one if lat2,long2 is zero

Comment: I don't understand the issue. You write the code I gave you in the comment above, after you shift it. So after this line `df[['Long_2','Lat_2']] = df[['Long','Lat']].shift(-1)`